# Understanding grades of steel for cookware. 18/10 vs 18/8

Tags: food-chemistry, reactivity, toxicity, alloy

I am looking for a stainless steel cookware and while researching on the best kind of stainless steel cookware, I came across this comment on youtube:

> Actually 18/10 steel is better and costlier. You're talking in terms of health hazard where more nickel (10) is considered more harmful than less (8). But in reality more nickel makes a pot sturdier and shinier and less prone to chemical leaching.

So, my question is, is it true that more nickel in case of stainless steel means less leaching? I know 18/10 is better in heat distribution, is sturdier and better than 18/8, but it also has more Nickle. To me, it doesn't make sense. But then again, chemistry was not subject. Or I am worrying too much and just get either 18/8 or 18/10 steel?

Comment: What about earthen pots for cooking? Most stainless steel cookware will leach very very tiny amounts of metals into food especially if it is acidic. Also mechanical abrasion while moving the spoon also introduces metal into food. Teflon coated stuff will leach Teflon. Iron pots will leach iron. There is no way out. Aluminum cookware is also used by millions for cooking.

Comment: See this link as well: https://www.rocheindustry.com/1810-stainless-steel-vs-188-stainless-steel/#The_corrosion_resistance_of_stainless_steel_188

Comment: @AChem Earthen pots also leach depending on what soil they used. I have been using aluminium pots till now. I heard stainless steel are much better than aluminium. I have thrown every teflon coated utensil.

Comment: @AChem I saw that link while researching. It still doesn't answer my question whether more nickle in 18/10 means less leaching or more.

Comment: I strongly suspect what you put in the pan will have a far greater effect on health than the precise make up of the steel the pan is made of.

Comment: @4-K, Please keep in mind that the body has an efficient unwanted stuff eliminating system as well via excretion. If you cook with oil, as is common in South Asian food, chances of metal leaching are even lower.

Comment: @abligh we usually use toamtoes.

Comment: @AChem I am least worried about leaching. I just want to understand that does more Nickle in 18/10 means that the added nickle actually helps in less leaching as in 18/8 or not. What the guy said in comments.

Comment: @4-K, You cannot make a generic statement and no wonder you cannot find more information. Corrosion is stated with respect to certain conditions. There are hundreds of foods and cooking conditions. We cannot make a generic statement. You are looking for a wrong question. You have to specify exact conditions for a comparison. Is 18/10 or 18/8 better for cooking. Nobody can give a general answer. Both of them are food grade. Don't worry too much.

Comment: May I ask what got you worried about cooking utensils?

Comment: @AChem "more nickel makes a pot sturdier and shinier **and less prone to chemical leaching**"  Is the part in bold true? That's my question.

Comment: @AChem We use aluminium (heavily pitted) and non-stick cookware. So We now switched to Iron utensils. But some dishes change flavour in iron utensil so we need a stainless steel stuff too. Indians traditionally used clay and iron utensils.

Comment: @4-K, Your bolded question cannot be answered because there is NO single cooking situation. Leaching will depend on conditions and there are infinite conditions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No stainless steel of the 18/8 family ( about 5 grades) leaches material in normal cooking service. Not to say they are immune to all possible abuse. The element that can make a difference is carbon, higher C can combine with more chrome removing it from solution where Cr provides the primary corrosion resistance. Not to worry, modern steel making generally gets C to 0.02 % max ( L grade).  I am trying to say for cookware there is no difference.

Comment: Being old , I recall Consumer Reports magazine evaluated stainless cookware over 50 years ago  One test was something like simmer sauerkraut for 100 hours.  they did find some pitting .  If that is not is recipe you use , no problem.

Comment: But what about nickle? Does more nickle means less leaching of metal in food as stated by that user in the comment? Or more nickle means more nickel leaching?

Comment: "Leeching " nickel from cookware sounds like it was written by a journalist, not a metallurgist. Closest  thing I can think of is nickel aluminum bronze may lose nickel in seawater under  rare circumstances.

Comment: Nickel is the least active metal in stainless steels so added nickel will not leach.  However, if the steel is of low quality and improperly melted etc nickel domains in the steel can be cathodic and hasten pitting corrosion of the iron and chromium. Workmanship is probably more important than 8 or10% nickel. For cooking acidic foods I use a well-seasoned cast iron saucepan [it does react a bit] or a Teflon coated saucepan. Storage is probably best in well washed polypropylene or polyethylene or soda-lime glass. [Glass leaches mostly harmless ions but breaks easily]